# How to separated UI by step number

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to ask your opinion. I have created a UI for a user form like the picture I shared. For now the question is on one page. My client asked for the questions to be divided by section. Example one page of the medical history section, the second page of the family history section and so on until page number six

[userForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZaVd.jpg)

I have separated the user form section by step number example step number one medical history. After finishing answering you need to press the next button to go to the second page. On the second page, there will be previous and next buttons. After entering last page 4 there will be previous and save buttons.

My code:

```
        int _stepno = 1;
                  
                _stepno == 1
                    ? Column(
                        //no1
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const Text(
                            "Past medical history: ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                height: 1.5),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          customRadio(
                              "Yes", "yes", _medicalhistory, "medicalhistory"),
                          if (_medicalhistory == "yes") ...[
                            const Text(
                                "If yes, please share and describe the previous medical illness: "),
                            const SizedBox(height: 5),
                            textformfieldWithoutLabel(_medicalillness, 1, true),
                         
                          ],
                          customRadio(
                              "No", "no", _medicalhistory, "medicalhistory"),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          const Text(
                            "Any previous medical check up with abnormal urine result/kidney test results: ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                height: 1.5),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          customRadio(
                              "Yes", "yes", _urineresult, "urineresult"),
                          customRadio("No", "no", _urineresult, "urineresult"),
                        ],
                      )
                    : const SizedBox(height: 0),
                
                _stepno == 2
                    ? Column(
                       
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const Text(
                            "Social history ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                height: 1.5),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                  child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  const Text(
                                    "Smoke: ",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        height: 1.5),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    height: 5,
                                  ),
                                  customRadio("Yes", "yes", _smoke, "smoke"),
                                  customRadio("No", "no", _smoke, "smoke"),
                                  const Text(
                                    "Alcohol: ",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        height: 1.5),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    height: 5,
                                  ),
                                  customRadio(
                                      "Yes", "yes", _alcohol, "alcohol"),
                                  customRadio("No", "no", _alcohol, "alcohol"),
                                  const Text(
                                    "Allergy:",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        height: 1.5),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    height: 5,
                                  ),
                                  customRadio(
                                      "Yes", "yes", _allergy, "allergy"),
                                  if (_allergy == "yes") ...[
                                    const Text(
                                        "If yes please share the allergic history:"),
                                    const SizedBox(height: 5),
                                    textformfieldWithoutLabel(
                                        _allergichistory, 1, true),
                                
                                  ],
                                  customRadio("No", "no", _allergy, "allergy"),
                                ],
                              ))
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    : const SizedBox(height: 0),
                
                _stepno == 3
                    ? Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const Text(
                            "Patient history/examination ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                height: 1.5),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          const Text(
                            "Swollen legs/ankles/feet/face: ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                height: 1.5),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          customRadio("Yes", "yes", _swollenhistory, "swollen"),
                          if (_swollenhistory == "yes") ...[
                            const Text("If yes, choose swollen body part/s:"),
                            const SizedBox(height: 5),
                            textformfieldWithoutLabel(_swollenbody, 1, true),
                           
                          ],
                          customRadio("No", "no", _swollenhistory, "swollen"),
                          const Text(
                            "Reduce urine output: ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                height: 1.5),
                          ),
                          customRadio(
                              "Yes", "yes", _urineoutput, "urineoutput"),
                          customRadio("No", "no", _urineoutput, "urineoutput"),
                          const Text(
                            "Weakness and fatigue: ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                height: 1.5),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          customRadio("Yes", "yes", _weakness, "weakness"),
                          customRadio("No", "no", _weakness, "weakness"),
                          const Text(
                            "Confusion:",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                height: 1.5),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          customRadio("Yes", "yes", _confusion, "confusion"),
                          customRadio("No", "no", _confusion, "confusion"),
                          const Text(
                            "Trouble sleeping: ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                height: 1.5),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          customRadio(
                              "Yes", "yes", _troublesleep, "troublesleep"),
                          customRadio(
                              "No", "no", _troublesleep, "troublesleep"),
                          const Text(
                            "Foamy/bubble urine: ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                height: 1.5),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          customRadio(
                              "Yes", "yes", _bubbleurine, "bubbleurine"),
                          customRadio("No", "no", _bubbleurine, "bubbleurine"),
                          const Text(
                            "Nausea/vomiting: ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                height: 1.5),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          customRadio("Yes", "yes", _vomiting, "vomiting"),
                          customRadio("No", "no", _vomiting, "vomiting"),
                          const Text(
                            "Dry/itchy skin: ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                height: 1.5),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          customRadio("Yes", "yes", _dry, "dry"),
                          customRadio("No", "no", _dry, "dry"),
                          const Text(
                            "Frequent cramps: ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                height: 1.5),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          customRadio("Yes", "yes", _cramps, "cramps"),
                          customRadio("No", "no", _cramps, "cramps"),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    const Text(
                                      "Other presenting complaints: ",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                          height: 1.5),
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                        child: textformfieldWithoutLabel(
                                            _complaints, 1, true)),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    : const SizedBox(height: 0),
            
  
          
          _stepno < 3
              ? Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: _stepno > 1
                          ? Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                              child: Center(
                                child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    _previous();
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: double.infinity,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 20, right: 20),
                                    height: 45,
                                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                      color: AppConst.primaryColor,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                        Radius.circular(5.0),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: const Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Previous",
                                        maxLines: 1,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          : const SizedBox(height: 1),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                        child: Center(
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              if (_stepno < 3) {
                                _verificationFormfieldAndMoveToNext();
                              }
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                              height: 45,
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                color: AppConst.primaryColor,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(5.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  _stepno == 0 ? "Next" : "Save",
                                  maxLines: 1,
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              : const SizedBox(height: 0),
              
              
              
              _previous() {
    if (_stepno > 1) {
      if (_stepno == 3) {
        setState(() {
          _completionPercentage = (_stepno / 100) * 10;
        });
      } else {
        _stepno--;
        setState(() {
          _completionPercentage = (_stepno / 100) * 10;
        });
      }
    }
  }
  
  _verificationFormfieldAndMoveToNext() async {
    if (_stepno == 1) {
      if (_medicalhistory == "n/a") {
        createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
        return;
      }
      if (_urineresult == "n/a") {
        createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
        return;
      }
      if (_medicalhistory == "yes") {
        if (_medicalillness.text.isEmpty) {
          createToast(_fToast, false,
              "Please share and describe the previous medical illness is empty");
          return;
        }
      }
    }


    if (_stepno == 2) {
      if (_smoke == "n/a") {
        createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
        return;
      }
      if (_alcohol == "n/a") {
        createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
        return;
      }
      if (_allergy == "n/a") {
        createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
        return;
      }
      if (_allergy == "yes") {
        if (_allergichistory.text.isEmpty) {
          createToast(_fToast, false, "Please share the allergic history");
          return;
        }
      }
    }


    if (_stepno == 3) {
      if (_swollenhistory == "n/a") {
        createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
        return;
      }
      if (_urineoutput == "n/a") {
        createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
        return;
      }
      if (_weakness == "n/a") {
        createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
        return;
      }
      if (_confusion == "n/a") {
        createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
        return;
      }
      if (_troublesleep == "n/a") {
        createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
        return;
      }
      if (_bubbleurine == "n/a") {
        createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
        return;
      }
      if (_vomiting == "n/a") {
        createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
        return;
      }
      if (_dry == "n/a") {
        createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
        return;
      }
      if (_cramps == "n/a") {
        createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
        return;
      }
      if (_complaints.text.isEmpty) {
        createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
        return;
      }
      if (_swollenhistory == "yes") {
        if (_swollenbody.text.isEmpty) {
          createToast(_fToast, false, "Please share swollen body part/s");
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I have shared the code that I have made. Sorry I can't share my full code as it exceeds the allowed limit. You can see how I did it separated section by step number. My problem now is after I separate by step number my UI does not come out in the form. The only thing that comes out is the title form and the next button. I have never made UI separate by step number. I'm not sure where my mistake is. Has anyone experienced something like this and how to solve this issue. I've also put in a LinearPercentIndicator and this widget doesn't come out either. I hope someone can help me.

[After separated by step number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKWcW.png)

[Example page structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCc28.png)

Comment: How s ur page structured ??

Comment: Please see the question. I have shared a picture of how the page is structured.

Comment: sorry, I meant you used particular logic to show the elements time at a time ??
Like your body contains a column with widget visibility inside?

Comment: Where is the logic for increasing stepno?